# open last used app from current app using Custom URL Schemes

Tags: ios, url-scheme

Am I able to open app from browser using Custom URL Schemes, now I need open a browser back this app after click cancel button in app. how can I open a browser? is it possible?

are can we open last used app from this app?

Answer (score 0):

You can open safari back with below line.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @"http://www.google.com"]];
```

However it will not open the browser with the state from where it went into background.

We can not open last used application. We can open it only if we know its custom URL.

Comment: ok, can we able to find the browser url here? - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation